# Can I make a sibling class with no parent?

Tags: python, class

I am making an ADSR and then using the ADSR to manipulate a wav file I've read. My issues is not about this actual process, but the class structure that I am trying to build around it. I'm trying to write this process as a method that will use variables from both an instance of Audio class, wav files, and my Envelope class, ADSR presets. I want to make these two classes sibling classes without a parent because the parent class serves no purpose besides linking the two subclasses (also I like for my code to have a tragic backstory.)

If this is not possible, how do fix my deadbeat parent class here so that I can have a method that uses variables from both subclasses. The one way I can think of is by taking all the variables used in all my subclasses, putting them in the parent class, and then have the subclasses inherit those variables, but that seems messy, especially if I were to apply this concept to a much larger project where I'm trying to connect say 30 different subclasses and then I've got a huge list of variables in my parent class. Is there a better way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write, read
class Sound:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def test_method (self):
# a method that uses variables from both subclasses

class Audio(Sound):
    def __init__(self,amplitude,sample_rate):
        Sound.__init__(self)
        self.amplitude=amplitude
        self.sample_rate=sample_rate
class Envelope(Sound):
    def __init__(self, atk, dec, sust, rel):
        Sound.__init__(self)
        self.atk = atk
        self.dec = dec
        self.sust = sust
        self.rel = rel
(Fs1, rawData1) =read('MySine.wav')
mySound1= Audio (rawData1,Fs1)
myEnv1= Envelope([0.1,1.0],[0.2,0.4],[0,0.3],[0.18,0])
```

Comment: `a method that uses variables from both subclasses` -  Why do you think that instances from separate subclasses can *automatically* share attributes because they have the same *parent*? Sounds like that could get messy especially with multiple instances of the subclasses..

Comment: Instead of a parent class, could you instead make a your `Sound` class accept `Audio` and `Sound` instances as arguments?  That way, you can do what you like with the values in those instances.  No tragic backstory here, though, I'm afraid.

Comment: For that matter, does `Sound` even *need* to be a class, or can `Sound.test_method` be a regular function that takes an `Audio` instance and a `Envelope` instance as arguments?